# Problem Using Active Reports in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, activereports

i tried to use Active Reports in Angular 9 and i did all the steps needed from this website,https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/docs/GettingStarted/QuickStart/QuickStart-Angular Still i get this error when i try to compile my app :

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@grapecity/activereports-angular" has missing dependencies:
 - rdlx-model
 - @grapecity/ar-js-viewer/ExportPanel
 - @grapecity/viewer-core
 - @grapecity/ar-js-viewer
 - @grapecity/viewer-core/features/search
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 9 uses Ivy compiler by default. You can disable Ivy in tsconfig.app.json file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

This should fix the issue.